# How to check if string has lowercase letter, uppercase letter and number

Tags: python

I need to make a simple password checker, it needs to check if the string has at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter and one number.

here's what i have

```
passwd = raw_input("enter your password: ")
upper = 0
lower = 0 
number = 0
while len(passwd) < 7 and upper <= 0 and lower <= 0 and number <= 0:
    print 'start'
    for x in passwd:
        if x.isupper()==True:
            print 'upper'
            upper+=1
        elif x.islower()==True:
            print 'lower'
            lower+=1
        elif x.isalpha()==False:
            print 'num'
            number+=1
    print ('password not complex enough')
    upper = 0
    lower = 0
    number = 0
    passwd = raw_input('please enter password again ')
```

those random looking prints are for debugging so i can see where it's reaching.

and what looks like is happening is that it only checks the first condition, the length condition and then leaves the loop.

here's a sample of what is happening

```
enter your password: pA1
start
lower
upper
num
password not complex enough
please enter password again password
```

why is it only checking the length condition? what did i do wrong?

Comment: _“why is it only checking the length condition?”_ - what makes you think it was only doing that? You get `lower`, `upper` and `num` in your output - where do you think that comes from, if not from those conditions? You just get `password not complex enough` because you output that _every_ time, completely independent of what your actual condition checks resulted in.

Comment: change `elif` to `if`

Comment: Your condition for `while` loop is `True` only in the first loop, because as soon as upper, lower or number gets `< 0` it will evaluate to `False`, because you're using `and`.

Comment: @CBroe I don't think it's only doing that, what i meant is that it only uses that condition to leave the loop, if the string is longer than 7 then it leaves the loop without checking if there are uppercase or lowercase letters

Comment: Well yeah, of course, because you made `len(passwd) < 7` one of the conditions that decides whether it even enters the loop body ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems with your checking logic. First of all you re-set your control variables before the `while` condition could check them. Furthermore you used `and` to test if all conditions are true, while `or` is what you should be using. If you want to keep the basic structure of your code, the best way to go is to use only `True` in your while statement and then `break` the loop once all conditions are fulfilled. Of course, as shown in the other answers, there are much more compact ways to check that all conditions are fulfilled.

```
passwd = raw_input("enter your password: ")
upper = 0
lower = 0 
number = 0
while True:
    for x in passwd:
        if x.isupper()==True:
            print 'upper'
            upper+=1
        elif x.islower()==True:
            print 'lower'
            lower+=1
        elif x.isalpha()==False:
            print 'num'
            number+=1
    if len(passwd) < 7 or upper <= 0 or lower <= 0 or number <= 0:
        print ('password not complex enough')
        passwd = raw_input('please enter password again ')
        upper = 0
        lower = 0
        number = 0
    else:
        break



print 'final password:', passwd
```

Output:

```
enter your password: pA
lower
upper
password not complex enough
please enter password again pA1ghlfx78
lower
upper
num
lower
lower
lower
lower
lower
num
num
final password: pA1ghlfx78
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there were better ways and more efficient ways to do it, the one i was thinking of was with Regex but wanted to keep it as simple to read as possible and i think this is the best way to do it

Answer (score 8):

You can simplify the whole logic by utilising `unicodedata.category` to collect what category of a character is and then check to see if all expected are present, eg:

```
import unicodedata

is_valid = (
    len(password) >= 7 and 
    {'Ll', 'Lu', 'Nd'}.issubset(unicodedata.category(ch) for ch in password)
)
```

Comment: Very nice. Though I'd prefer `{'Ll', 'Lu', 'Nd'} <= set(map(unicodedata.category, password))` or `{'Ll', 'Lu', 'Nd'}.issubset(map(unicodedata.category, password))`.

Comment: @Stefan going for the `.issubset` to allow it to take any iterable and avoid the explicit creation of a `set` and the gen-comp instead of `map` to keep it functionally the same in Py 2 and Py3... (avoiding an unnecessary `list` built in Py 2)... But yeah... they'll all work...

Comment: Hmm, ok, although a list as long as a password is probably not that terribly wasteful :-)

Comment: @Stefan a very fair point :)

Comment: I wanted to do it the simplest and most readable way possible, this seemed like the right thing for me. I was thinking about using Regex to make it simpler but your way is fantastic

Comment: Surprisingly, this is *slower* than [pure sets solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45878517/244297) (just did a check using `%timeit` in ipython).

Answer (score 1):

If a password must consist of *ASCII letters and numbers* only, then the most efficient approach would be to use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits

def is_valid(password):
    if len(password) < 7:
        return False
    password_set = set(password)
    return not any(password_set.isdisjoint(x)
                   for x in (ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits))
```

If unicode characters are allowed, you could use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#any):

```
 def is_valid(password):
     return (len(password) >= 7 and
             any(c.islower() for c in password) and
             any(c.isupper() for c in password) and
             any(c.isdigit() for c in password))
```

Answer (score -1):

May this is helpful for you.I use `sum(1 for c in the string if c.islower())` to find the total number of lowercase. and same way to find the total number of uppercase and digit.`len(string)` to find length of string.

```
string=input()
if ((sum(1 for c in string if c.islower())>=1) and (sum(1 for c in string if 
c.isupper())>=1) and (sum(1 for c in string if c.isdigit())>=1) and (len(string)>=7)):
    print("Password is complex")
else:
    print ("Password not complex enough")
```

Comment: Why devote?Any problem with the answer?