# python regex for password validation

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following requirement to validate the password with below context

- at least one digit
- at least one uppercase letter
- at least one lowercase letter
- at least one special character[$@#]

Below program is doing the partial match but not the full regex

```
#!/usr/sfw/bin/python
import re
password = raw_input("Enter string to test: ")
if re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9@#$]{6,12}', password):
    print "match"
else:
    print "Not Match"
```

In use:

```
localhost@user1$ ./pass.py
Enter string to test: abcdabcd
match
```

It is evaluating the wrong output. Can anyone suggest here should I use `re.search`?

Comment: `'abcdabcd'` *does* match your regular expression, it has between 6 and 12 characters in the list of valid characters.

Comment: only Valid inputs are like abcd123A#, abcd123A$, abcd123A@. it should not accept any other input as abcd233AA#*. see below output 
localhost@user1$ ./pass.py
Enter string to test: abcd233AA#*
match

Comment: And those *also* match the regex, but the expression you've written **does not** enforce your list of requirements.

Comment: can you suggest me the regex to enforce the requirements ?

Comment: You might also want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45878324/how-to-check-if-string-has-lowercase-letter-uppercase-letter-and-number/ and possibly use/adapt one of the solutions there...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the Regex for at least one digit, one uppercase letter, at least one lowercase letter, at least one special character

```
import re
password = input("Enter string to test: ")
# Add any special characters as your wish I used only #@$
if re.match(r"^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$])[\w\d@#$]{6,12}$", password):
    print ("match")
else:
    print ("Not Match")
```

Hope this will Help You...

Comment: localhost@user1$ ./pass.py
Enter string to test: abcd123A#
Not Match
it is failed
Only allowed special chacter are $,@ and #

Comment: @MuthuKumar replace `.+` inside each lookaheads with `.*` , in the above regex, first lookahead expects a char to be present before the digit. But in this example `2abcdjgA#`, there isn't any char before 2. So it would fail.